# How to pick text file for code from terminal

Tags: node.js

Lately, I've been working with reading text files by hardcoding them inside.

```
let filename = "input.txt"
let data = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/" + filename).toString().split(/\r?\n/)
```

This leads me to wonder how could I replace it with something I would specify in terminal while loading the code 
(I mean by writing something like:

```
node index.js input.txt
```

).
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is command line arguments.

try to create a `test.js` file with this single line :

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

It will behave like this :

```
$ node test.js
> [ '/usr/bin/node', '/tmp/test.js' ]
$ node test.js some command line arguments
> [ '/usr/bin/node',
    '/tmp/test.js',
    'some',
    'command',
    'line',
    'arguments' ]
```

So for your case (taking a file name) you need this :

```
const filename = process.argv[2] || 'defaultFileName.txt'
let data = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/" + filename).toString().split(/\r?\n/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the input arguments are stored in `process.argv`